# Azure Mobile App Service - force load of sub item in REST API

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile app service, that represents Employee and Company.

There's also a many to many table to represent when an employee works for a company (and can work for more than one).

So the basic structure is

```
public class Employee : EntityData
{
    public string Id{get;set;} etc
    public List<EmployeeCompanyRelationship> EmployeeCompanyRelationships{get;set;}
}


public class Company : EntityData
{
    public string Id{get;set;} etc
}

public class EmployeeCompanyRelationship : EntityData
{
     public Employee Employee{get;set;}
     public Company Company{get;set;}
     public bool IsCurrentEmployee{get;set;}
}
```

However when I then GET on Employee's controller the EmployeeCompanyRelationships is not populated.  If I expose EmployeeCompanyRelationship with its own controller, I get something like the following

```
[{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2016-05-21T23:04:49.407Z","createdAt":"2016-05-21T23:04:49.391Z","version":"AAAAAAAACNc=","id":"09fa0daf-ba36-4146-ba9c-c0836fda4275:126ff9b8-b90e-4c82-9e3e-4331f7126cce","isCurrentEmployee":true
```

Is there a way I can force either Employee or EmployeeCompanyRelationship to include their related entities in serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: no

Longer version: See my blog post on the subject: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/

Comment: Good to know - I wish MS would highlight this in their demos, as it differs from the usual EF way of doing things pretty significantly.

I'll modify my entities to instead show the FK instead so it can be reassembled on the client side.

Comment: Agreed - I'm intending a big revamp of the documentation real soon - it's turning into a book.  Once we've got a skeleton available, it will go on learn.microsoft.com.  Stay tuned!